# adding a uielement on a view which has programmatically create scroll view in ios

Tags: ios

i have created a uiscrollview programmatically in iOS now i want to add certain labels over that scroll view using interface builder.
can we do that and if yes then how.

Comment: Welcome to SO! :) Please, take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get your first shiny badge :) Also, you should add some of your code, you wrote you created `uiscrollview` programmatically -- how?

Comment: If you are creating labels using interface builder then create scrollview also there in your storyboard or xib